# OpenCSV CSVWriter adds blank line to end of file

Tags: java

I'm using the following code to remove quotemarks from a pipe-delimited CSV:

```
public Path truncateQuoteMarks(Path path) throws Exception {

    String pipeDelimitedFilename = path.toAbsolutePath().toString();

    Path convertedFilename = Paths.get(pipeDelimitedFilename.substring(0, pipeDelimitedFilename.lastIndexOf(".csv")) + "_no_quotes.csv");

    CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(path.toAbsolutePath().toString()))), '|', CSVParser.DEFAULT_QUOTE_CHARACTER);

    reader.skip(1);

    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(convertedFilename.toAbsolutePath().toString());
    fw.write(System.lineSeparator());
    CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(fw, '|', CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER, CSVWriter.RFC4180_LINE_END);

    String[] currentLine;
    while((currentLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
        writer.writeNext(currentLine);
    }

    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
    reader.close();

    return convertedFilename;
}
```

However, it leaves a blank line at the end of the csv (see picture). 
[image]

Upon googling i found that this has been asked at least once both [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40579601/how-to-remove-empty-line-at-the-end-of-the-file) and in another site. The other site claims that this is the way OpenCSV works and suggested editing the file size, but there has to be other ways.

Is there a way to remove this blank line from the end of the file? SQL Server `BULKINSERT` does not like it at all.

Answer (score 0):

According to [RFC4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) the final lineending is optional. So a writer can or can not write it. The openCSVWriter has not option to create a final without line ending. You can extend the Class and add a setter for the line ending and set it empty before writing the last line or write it manual.

For each of this possibilities you should have a look at the source of the [writer](https://sourceforge.net/p/opencsv/source/ci/master/tree/src/main/java/com/opencsv/CSVWriter.java#l147).

Comment: it's not the line ending i'm concerned about, it's the blank line at the end shown by the blue-ish color

Comment: A line is defined by the final line ending. Without this there is no empty line at the end. Try just to remove the line ending and import the file again.